how/can i make .so files for files in one place and move them to another so gcc linker can find them automatically?
installed and made allegro5 with addons on linux mint with cmake in /home/qweqqweq/allegro5/build.  must make addons work without gcc flags by generating .o and .so files from there and put in /usr/local.  how?  where to make the .o and .so files? can move them after made?
Need to make .so files for allegro addons cause it didn't come with or make them during install/making it with cmake.  question is where do I put them, and how?
I want to make them in my ~/home/qweqqweq/allegro5 directory and then move them to /usr/local.  i've already made a new config file to make the gcc linker search /usr/local for libraries and i don't want to make the linker include even more directories in its standard searches if possible.

It seems you are looking for "install" word. After building the project (with make) you may install it (make install), so all files, needing for using the package, will be put into the system location.

The standard procedure for building and installing a package with a GNU Make
build system (whether you wrote the Makefile(s) yourself or generated them with CMake or otherwise) is to run $ make in the build directory, followed (if that is successful) by $ sudo make install By default this will install all the build targets in the appropriate subdirectories of /usr/local.
